# Difference between ++ and ++= in scala

Tags: scala

```
object Dcoder extends App {
  var c = scala.collection.immutable.Map(12 -> "jd", 13 -> "ff")
  c = c ++ Map(16 -> "hh", 17 -> "℅")
  println(c)

  c ++= Map(18 -> "|||")
  println(c)
}
```

`a = a ++ Map()` as well as `a ++= Map()` performs concatenation. Does `a=a++b` and `a++=b` mean the same?

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes they are the same, sometimes they are not.

If the collection is immutable (e.g. [`List`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html)), then it has no special method called `++=`, so the statement

```
collection ++= someOtherCollection
```

is syntactic sugar, and it is desugared into

```
collection = collection ++ someOtherCollection
```

On the other hand, most mutable collections (e.g. [`ListBuffer`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.html)) have a special `++=` method, so that

```
collection ++= someOtherCollection
```

mutates `collection` in-place by adding all elements `someOtherCollection`.

---

To see that `++=` and `= ... ++` really behave differently, consider the following two examples:

```
var x = collection.mutable.ListBuffer(1, 2, 3)
val y = collection.mutable.ListBuffer(4, 5)
val z = x

x ++= y

println(x)
println(z)
```

This prints

```
ListBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
ListBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

But

```
var x = collection.mutable.ListBuffer(1, 2, 3)
val y = collection.mutable.ListBuffer(4, 5)
val z = x

x = x ++ y

println(x)
println(z)
```

prints

```
ListBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
ListBuffer(1, 2, 3)
```

because `++` forces the creation of a completely new collection, that is not referenced by `z`.

Answer (score 0):

Its the same as `a = a+2` and `a+=2` in case of Integer

For second question, `a=a++b` and `a++=b` depends on the type of a and b. Depends if they support ++ and ++= operator or not

Comment: In which collection ++ is not present but ++= is or viseversa??